# Keeping track of basis changes when computing the smith normal form

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

I don't understand how to keep track of the basis change as you compute smith normal form. We did an example in lecture where:

$A = \begin{pmatrix}
[1] & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
\end{pmatrix}$

Where [1] is the pivot position. The first operations performed were:
$R_2\mapsto R_2 - 5R_1$
$R_3\mapsto R_3 - 9R_1$.

Which then gives:
$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
0 & -4 & -8 & -12 \\
0 & -8 & -16 & -24 \\
\end{pmatrix}$.

He then writes: $U\mapsto V$: Basis of V:
$\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
5\\
9 \\
\end{pmatrix}$
$\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
1\\
0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$
$\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0\\
1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$.
Afterwards, he column transformations:
$C_2\mapsto C_2 - 5C_1$
$C_3\mapsto C_3 - 9C_1$
$C_4\mapsto C_4 - 4C_1$
Getting
$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -4 & -8 & -12 \\
0 & -8 & -16 & -24 \\
\end{pmatrix}$ and basis of U:
$\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
0\\
0 \\
0\\
\end{pmatrix}$
$\begin{pmatrix}
-2\\
-1\\
0 \\
0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$
$\begin{pmatrix}
-3\\
0\\
1 \\
0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$
$\begin{pmatrix}
-4\\
0\\
0 \\
1 \\ \end{pmatrix}$

and then so on, updating the basis after each step. What I don't understand is how these basis are found after each step.

Comment: You're not explaining things clearly. You keep referring to a "the basis", but presumably there should be two bases: one of the domain and one of the codomain.  Also, it's not clear what $U$ and $V$ are supposed to refer to

Comment: @BenGrossmann I think he was referring to U being the domain and V being the codomain. By the basis I mean the basis of both the domain and codomain.

Comment: Ok, but there are two different bases, not just one basis. There is no "basis of both the domain and codomain", there is "a basis of the domain" and separately "a basis of the codomain".

Comment: Oh yeah, no I understand that part. I worded my response badly, sorry. I meant keep track of both the basis of the domain and basis of the codomain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can think of the decomposition process as follows: starting with $A_0 = A$, $P_0 = I_3$, and $Q_0 = I_4$, we go from $(A_k,P_k,Q_k)$ to $(A_{k+1},P_{k+1},Q_{k+1})$ in such a way that at all points in the process, we have $A = P_k A_k Q_k$. Note that $P_k$ is a change of basis matrix over the codomain and $Q_k$ is a change of basis matrix over the domain.

On the other hand, note that applying a row-operation to $A$ amounts to computing $RA$ for some invertible matrix $R$. Similarly, applying a column-operation to $A$ amounts to computing $C^{-1}A$ for some invertible matrix $C$.

With all that established, consider the following. We begin with

$$
A = \overbrace{\pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1}}^{P_0}
\overbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
\end{pmatrix}}^{A_0}
\overbrace{\pmatrix{1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1}}^{Q_0}.
$$
Applying your row operations amounts to the multiplication $RA$, where
$$
R = \pmatrix{1&0&0\\-5&1&0\\-9&0&1}.
$$
Note: to find the matrix corresponding to a certain sequence of row operations, simply apply those operations to the identity matrix. Similarly, the matrix corresponding to a certain sequence of columns operations can be found by applying those operations to an identity matrix.

With that in mind, we have $A = (P_0R^{-1})(RA_0)Q_0$. That is, we can take $P_1 = P_0R^{-1} = R^{-1}$. Note that the inverse of $R$ will be the matrix corresponding to the reverse of the row operations associated with $R$.

Similarly, the column operations applied to $A$ are those corresponding to the matrix
$$
C = \pmatrix{1&-2&-3&-4\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1}.
$$
With that in mind, we have
$$
A = (P_0R^{-1})(RA_0C)(C^{-1}Q_0).
$$
That is, our work so far amounts to taking $P_1 = P_0R^{-1} = R^{-1}$, $A_1 = RA_0C$, and $Q_1 = C^{-1}Q_0 = C^{-1}$.

---

After continuing these process, we will eventually end up with $A_k$ equal to the Smith normal form $A_k = D$, so that $A = P_k D Q_k$ is a Smith normal form decomposition. We will have $P_k = R_1^{-1}R_2^{-1} \cdots R_k^{-1}$ for some sequence of row operations with corresponding matrices $R_1,\dots,R_k$. Similarly, we will have $Q_k = C_k^{-1} \cdots C_2^{-1}C_1^{-1}$.

$P_k$ is a change of basis matrix that takes us **to** the desired basis from the standard basis. Thus, the columns of $P_k$ are the elements of that basis. $Q_k$ is a change of basis that takes us **from** the desired basis to the standard basis. Thus, the columns of $Q_k^{-1} = C_1C_2 \cdots C_k$ will be the elements of that basis.

Comment: Thank you so much!